# Windows update, adding roles not working after adding to domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, windows-server-2012

I am having a bit of an issue here, after adding my server to my home domain, I can no longer use windows update (error code 8024402F - which I believe is a connectivity issue). Also cannot use the add roles and features dialog.

On a side note, I can use the internet, but it is rather slow. Also, pinging (e.g. google.com) initially takes a while (2-3 seconds before a response), after subsequent ping requests are normal.

This sounds like a DNS issue to me? But I need some help!

My setup is as follows:
DC is a server 2012 core machine, DNS servers here are set to the DNS servers provided by my ISP.

The server I am working on is a server 2012 r2 machine. DNS server here is my DC.

In a setup like this, my DC should be the DNS server for all machines connected to the domain? Which should then pass requests to the DNS servers for my ISP?

So server (in domain) -> DNS server on DC -> DNS servers provided by ISP.

I've reconfigured my DC so that the dns server on the NIC points to itself, and then set up dns forwarders to my ISP's dns servers. This seems to have fixed everything?!?! (Internet no longer slow, windows update works as does add roles and services). Could this be the source of the problem?

Comment: Your DC/DNS server should use itself for DNS in it's DNS client settings. You can then configure the DNS server to forward DNS requests to your ISP.

Comment: Could you point me into the right direction as to how to do that? Set up DNS to forward requests to the ISP DNS servers?

Comment: Open the DNS Manager console. Right click the server and select Properties from the context menu. Click the forwarders tab. Add the ip addresses of the ISP DNS servers. In the TCP/IP properties of the server NIC make sure it's set to point to itself for DNS.

Comment: Hmmm your suggestion of dns forwarders seems to have fixed all my issues!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the DNS Manager console. Right click the server and select Properties from the context menu. Click the forwarders tab. Add the ip addresses of the ISP DNS servers. In the TCP/IP properties of the server NIC make sure it's set to point to itself for DNS.

Comment: Glad to help...